# character(0) get the first table but canot get to second table on pae

Tags: screen-scraping, rvest

Trying to webscrape from HTML.
Using Inspector gadget. 
No problems with the 1st table on page. With 2nd table, Iget character(0) or Nodeset(0)

```
library(rvest)
library(plyr)
date1=20161011
gdf1 <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 11, nrow = 1))
newdate<-date1
# HOCKEY 
year<-2015

#  date1=newdate[d]
date1=2010

#for (yr in 1:10){
  date1=date1+1
  c<-paste("https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_",date1,".html",sep="")


  nbc<-read_html(c)
  nbc
  #tables<-html_nodes(nbc,".center , #games , .right:nth-child(5), .right:nth-child(3), #games a")
  tables<-html_nodes(nbc,"#stats .right , #stats a")
  g<-html_text(tables)
```

Comment: you sure your generated urls are correct? Can you supply a couple of the urls?

Comment: https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2019.html    https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2018.html  If you look at it. I can get the standings table at the top and individual games but cannot get the Statistics Table.    Thank you for taking a look at this.  I am new to this and  am struggling finding readings/videos/books to help.